# Como realizar o desvio de fluxo correto em uma integração com vários sistemas?

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software, integração

Possuímos um sistema, que chamarei de A, que atende a alguns clientes. Estamos agora realizando as primeiras integrações com os sistemas internos (ERP) desses clientes. Ao fazermos, por exemplo, uma requisição para o web service do Sistema A, o mesmo deve mapear essa requisição para um web service específico de integração (disponibilizado pelo cliente), desse modo os dados vão parar diretamente no banco de dados dos ERPs de cada cliente.

O fluxo pode ser resumido no seguinte:

> *Requisição Web Service Sistema A → Requisição Web Service de Integração Cliente → Banco de Dados do cliente*

Porém, nem todos os clientes possuem ou irão sequer possuir integração com seus sistemas internos, então, o fluxo para eles continua sendo esse:

> *Requisição Web Service Sistema A → Banco de Dados Sistema A*

Atualmente, o Web Service do Sistema A é feito em Java, utilizando Jersey e o Padrão REST.

Para cada classe Resource, que é onde existem os mapeamentos dos endpoints com Jersey, existe também uma classe Service específica. Nas classes services residem toda lógica de negócios existente. Por fim, o trio se completa com uma classe DAO, que é responsável pelo CRUD dos dados no banco.

Assim, dado uma funcionalidade qualquer no Sistema A, poderiam existir as seguintes classes:

**RESOURCE**

```
@Path("/funcionalidade")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public class FuncionalidadeResource {
    private final FuncionalidadeService service = new FuncionalidadeService();

    @GET
    @Path("/exemplo")
    public String getExemplo() {
        return service.getExemplo();
    }
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public class FuncionalidadeService {
    private final FuncionalidadeDao dao = new FuncionalidadeDao();

    public String getExemplo() {
        // Lógica de negócios necessária aqui
        return dao.getExemplo();
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public class FuncionalidadeDao {

    public String getExemplo() {
        // Consulta o banco de dados aqui
        return "Um dado buscado do banco";
    }
}
```

Todas os Services e Daos possuem interfaces, que foram ocultadas aqui por brevidade.

Com isso, minha dúvida é a seguinte, como fazer para que para determinados clientes (aqueles que possuirem integração) a requisição seja desviada para seus web services e nunca chegue de fato a utilizar a DAO do Sistema A?

Um outro ponto que adiciona complexidade: uma única funcionalidade pode ter inúmeros métodos em seu Resource, porém, não necessariamente todos serão integrados. Isso quer dizer que: para a mesma funcionalidade, em algumas requisições a busca deve acontecer no banco de dados do cliente e para outras no banco de dados do Sistema A.

Até agora, pensei em uma possível solução para esse problema:

Ao receber a requisição do cliente no web service do Sistema A, verificamos se o cliente que realiza a requisição possui integração com essa função específica. Isso, imaginei, poderia ser feito fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados, onde cada funcionalidade teria seu código único junto ao código do cliente. Bastaria informarmos o código do cliente e o código da funcionalidade para saber se ele possui integração para ela.
Porém, isso não resolve todo o problema, já que dentro de uma mesma funcionalidade pode-se haver métodos que possuem integração ou não. Sendo assim, cada método de uma funcionalidade precisaria também possuir um código único no banco de dados. Com isso, em cada requisição passaríamos o código único desse método junto com o código do cliente para saber se o cliente possui integração para esse método.
Supondo que essa parte anterior funcione, o próximo passo seria, caso o cliente possuísse integração, como faríamos o desvio para seu web service ao invés da nossa DAO?
Para *solucionar* isso, pensei em adicionar mais um nível na arquitetura do web service do Sistema A. Ficando assim o fluxo de uma requisição que possuísse integração dentro do web service:

Resource → Service → **Router** → DAO

A nova camada, de Routers, existiria apenas para as funções que possuíssem algum tipo de integração com qualquer cliente. Ela seria a responsável por verificar se o cliente possui integração para aquele método específico, se possuir, repassaria para outra classe a demanda de realizar essa requisição no web service do cliente. Se não, ela apenas chamará o método DAO do Sistema A.

Desse modo, a classe Router vai possuir uma referência a DAO do Sistema A, que antes ficava no Service e também uma referência a alguma espécie de RequestDispatcher para poder passar a essa classe a demanda de dar continuidade a uma requisição que possua integração.

Nessa abordagem, duas coisas me soam muito estranhas e eu ainda não as aceitei muito bem:

- O fato de cada método do Resource ter que possuir um código único para poder vincular, no banco de dados, ao cliente que possuir integração. Isso parece muito sujeito a erros e de difícil gerenciamento quanto mais o software cresce.
- Caso o Router descubra que o cliente tem uma integração naquele método específico, como ele vai saber qual RequestDispatcher instanciar? Cada cliente deveria ter o seu. Para cada funcionalidade integrada. Essa criação pode ser demandada para uma factory, porém, essa factory teria que possuir o código dos clientes hardcoded para poder instanciar o Dispatcher correto? Me soa como code smell.

Como eu disse, essa possível solução não me convenceu pelos contras que ela adiciona, por isso gostaria de ideias e sugestões. Quem sabe alguém que já tenha tido experiência com isso saiba nos dizer o caminho menos turbulento a se seguir.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Resource → Service → Router → DAO

Eu diria que esse fluxo não está correto. É mais parecido a isto

```
                               / Base de dados
Resource - Service - Router __/ 
                              \ 
                               \ Web Service
```

> O fato de cada método do Resource ter que possuir um código único para
>   poder vincular, no banco de dados, ao cliente que possuir integração.
>   Isso parece muito sujeito a erros e de difícil gerenciamento quanto
>   mais o software cresce.

Porquê? Use GUID's como identificadores. [Eles são estatisticamente únicos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39771).

> Caso o Router descubra que o cliente tem uma integração naquele método
>   específico, como ele vai saber qual RequestDispatcher instanciar? **Cada
>   cliente deveria ter o seu.** Para cada funcionalidade integrada...

## Obrigue o ERP a seguir determinadas regras impostas por você.

Esta ideia pode ser absurda mas é exatamente assim que toda a Internet funciona. É exatamente pelo fato do `HTTP` ser standard que você pode aceder a qualquer página da Internet através do browser. Imagine os servidores a usarem cada um o seu protocolo. O browser teria que suportar todos os protocolos?

Estas regras não tem que ser muito especificas. Você só tem que indicar, por exemplo, que só suporta integrações com servidores `HTTP`. E que os dados estão num formato especificado por você. (por exemplo `JSON`, ou `XML` com um formato por si definido). É também importante especificar onde esses dados podem ser obtidos (query string, ou body)

Caso os clientes queiram o `XML` noutro formato você pode usar `XSLT` para fazer transformações. Cabe a você decidir se esse `XSLT` é definido por você ou pelo cliente.

Se não quiser impor URLS definidos por você, eles poderão estar presentes num ficheiro de configuração, que indica que URL usar para cada funcionalidade.

**Isto vai-lhe permitir escrever apenas um módulo que funciona com todos ERPs**

## O ERP não  está disposto a seguir as suas regras

Então você vai ter mesmo que fazer uma integração especifica para esse ERP. Eu cobraria mais dinheiro nessas situações ;)

## Modelando as suas necessidades com UML

Eu fiz um UML que poderá atender as suas necessidades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A intenção é que Você tenha uma interface `IOperacoes` que indique todas as operações que você pode realizar. Essas operações sao implementadas em 3 entidades com fins diferentes.

A primeira entidade é a entidade responsável por realizar as operações concretamente ditas. `ImplementaOperacoes`

A segunda entidade é a entidade responsável por usar uma forma de integração. `IntregradorHTTP` e `IntegradorBaseDeDados`.

A terceira entidade é o `Router`, que para determinada operação chama os intregadores para todos os ERPS (ou outra lógica por si definida).

De forma a suportar vários Erps foi definida a interface `IErp`. Esta interface especifica os integradores que cada `IErp` suporta. Neste caso ela também contém informação sobre os URls do ERP para cada Operação.

Por exemplo você pode implementar o `Router` de forma a que se um `URL` for `null` ou vazio, você automaticamente usa o `IntregradorBaseDedados`

Comment: Olá, Bruno. Sua alternativa ao fluxo também está correta. Porém, tem momentos que vou acessar apenas a DAO, outros o WS (do ERP). Quem sabe em alguns casos até mesmo ambos. Entendo o seu argumento e concordo que não há outra alternativa que não seja criar identificadores únicos para cada método, certo? Porém, na factory dos `RequestDispatcher` eu precisaria também ter o código único de cada cliente hardcoded, para poder instanciar o objeto correto, ou não? Eu não tenho muito como escapar de fazer essa comunicação com cada ERP específico. Mesmo sendo mais caro, é isso que os clientes querem.

Comment: @Luiz Os identificadores nao sao para os métodos mas sim para os objetos que vai guardar na base de dados. Não sei. Vai ter que dar detalhes dos vários ERPs para ter uma ideia melhor da situação.  Se todos os ERPs obedecerem ás regras que eu disse voce pode fazer apenas 1 modulo e ter uma pasta por cada ERP. Essas pastas apenas vao ter um ou mais ficheiros de configuracao.

Comment: @Luiz Editei a resposta.

Comment: Boa resposta! Porém, acredito que ela não seja muito escalável. Uma interface para definir todas as operações logo se tornaria algo grande demais. Um outro ponto, é que para eu usar o `IntegradorBaseDeDados`, seria necessário que minhas DAOs implementassem, provavelmente, IOperacoes, isso se eu entendi bem o que você quis dizer. Na verdade, não ficou muito claro pra mim onde as DAOs entrariam nesse modelo. Não consigo encaixar essa solução com o grande número de DAOs que existem no projeto.

Comment: @Luiz o número de operações por maior que seja é efêmero. Não, as suas Daos não tem que implementar Ioperacoes. Mas você receberia uma implementação delas no seu integrador de base de dados. Consoante a operação que queira fazer pode usar um número arbitrário de operações dos seus DAOs

Comment: Apesar de não ter atendido especificamente as minhas necessidades, me baseei no seu UML para criar a e implementar a versão que estamos utilizando. Agradeço a dedicação em ajudar, foi muito útil. Mais que merecido a recompensa. Obrigado! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Isolamento de serviços por contexto e depois suas integrações são tópicos de bastante discussão. E claro, cada estratégia de integração depende muito do cenário e dos recursos disponíveis.

Eu gosto muito das estratégias:

> App A >> Message >> App B

Ou, para seu cenário, a primeira vista:

> App A >> Message >> Processor >> Message >> App B

Assim, no seu `Processor` se executa as regras de fluxo - com *toggle feature* por exemplo - e dispara ou não uma mensagem para a aplicação destino - ERP.